# Need help understanding the use of collections in lambda statements

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I've got a part of a lambda statement that came from Map <'String, Double> that I don't quite understand.

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
              Map.Entry::getValue, (String, Double) -> String,
              LinkedHashMap::new);
```

Here is what I think it means:

```
Map.Entry::getKey is stating variable String,
Map.Entry::getValue is stating variable Double
```

Don't quite understand what (String, Double) -> String, LinkedHashMap::new.
Is it creating a LinkedHashMap with String as the keyvalue? But then why is Double in (String, Double) needed?

Another example that is part of Map

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting());

then followed by...

.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> 
entry.getKey().charAt(0), TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList());
```

What do they all actually mean?

Comment: take a look at the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html there are three signature of that groupingBy method each one has a description that describe what to do exactly

Comment: Unless `String` is a variable in current scope, `(String, Double) -> String` cannot be valid (even if it's already bad enough by declaring variables using class names).

Comment: `(String, Double) -> String` is the same as `(a, b) -> a`. `String` and `Double` are variable names. Seems like whoever wrote it doesn't know what they're doing, or they're trying to confuse people who read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toMap` version you've mentioned consumes a `keyMapper` function which is used to extract the map keys hence the `Map.Entry::getKey`, a `valueMapper` function which is used to extract the map values hence the `Map.Entry::getValue`, a merge function used to resolve collisions in case there are two keys that are equal hence the `(String, Double) -> String` (which basically says "if two given keys are equal then keep the value of the first and discard the second") and finally the `LinkedHashMap::new` states that result of the reduction should be stored in a `LinkedHashMap` instance.

The second example snippet you've provided:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,
                  TreeMap::new, 
            Collectors.counting());
```

States that the elements of the stream will be grouped by the strings lowercased, the results of the reduction will be accumulated into a `TreeMap` and the map values will be the count of each string occurrence in the stream. So, the resulting map will be `TreeMap<String, Long>`.

The third example snippet you've provided:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey().charAt(0), 
          TreeMap::new, 
          Collectors.toList());
```

States that the elements of the stream will be grouped by the first character of the entry keys, the result of the reduction will be accumulated into a `TreeMap` and the values is a list of the elements of the stream. So, the resulting map is a `TreeMap<Character, List<T>>` where `T` is the type of elements in the stream.

---

Further, you can check out the [Collectors API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) and experiment with it and/or see the [Guide to Java 8’s Collectors](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors).

Comment: Actually, after multiple times reading it, I've got it! Thanks! If you did get a notification I was actually asking about (String, Double) -> String but then I realised that this is the merge. I thought it was comparing the merged keys when you said this '(which basically says "if two given keys are equal then keep the value of the first and discard the second")'.